# Mocking SOAPpy method call

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to mock a SOAPProxy call, setting a return value, but it is refusing to work:

```
@patch('SOAPpy.SOAPProxy')
def test_check_cedible_mock(self, mock_soappy):
    mock_soappy.getToken.return_value = ':)'
    #calling the function...
```

In the function, it is used like this:

```
from SOAPpy import SOAPProxy
_server = SOAPProxy(url, ns)
tree = etree.fromstring(signed_seed)
ss = etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True, encoding='iso-8859-1')
resp = etree.fromstring(_server.getToken(ss).encode('utf-8'))
```

But _server.getToken(ss) is returning a MagickMock object.

How can I make it to work? Thanks.